# Is there a way to use NVARCHAR2 data type in COLUMNS clause of JSON_TABLE?

Tags: json, oracle

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  sample_json   NVARCHAR2(111):= '[{"NAME":"ĄŚĆĘąśćę"},{"NAME":"ЙйКкЛлМм"}]';
  part          NVARCHAR2(111);
BEGIN
 SELECT j.name into part
   FROM JSON_TABLE(sample_json,
                   '$[*]' COLUMNS 
                   name NVARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.NAME'
                  ) j
   WHERE j.name ='ЙйКкЛлМм';
END;
```

Got this error:

> `PL/SQL: ORA-40484:`
> My DB NLS_CHARACTERSET: EE8ISO8859P2

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Your code throws `PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected..` and after adding `INTO` you get `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more..`

Comment: Please also add what is your database character set and what you try to achieve / avoid.